# How to NOT embed fonts in Apache FOP

Tags: apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP to create PDFs.
I have a set of fonts for which i do not want to embed. The reason i don't want to embed the fonts is because of the file size.

I tried this in the font configuration by referencing it:

```
 <font name="XYZ" kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts/XYZ.ttf">
           <font-triplet name="XYZ" style="normal" weight="normal" />
           <font-triplet name="any" style="normal" weight="normal" />
 </font>
 <referenced-fonts>
           <match font-family="XYZ" />
  </referenced-fonts>
```

But this did not help. And the fonts appeared incorrect.
How do i not embed the font?